# How to customize toolbar in Bottomsheet layout?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, bottom-sheet

I'm using a CollapsingToolbarLayout within a CoordinatorLayout for my bottomsheet's layout. The layout looks like this -

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkBackgroundMainTranslucent"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorScrim"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/poster_string"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/bottomsheet_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bottomsheet_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I was wondering whether it would be possible to customize the toolbar inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout to add an up button and set its title without setting that toolbar as the supportactionbar.

Answer (score -1):

you can put icons/images/button inside the toolbar through xml like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/bottomsheet_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageButton 
                  ... your usual crud height/width ...
                  android:id="@+id/contact_detail_edit/>

            <TextView />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then access them through the toolbar like so:

```
        Toolbar bottomSheetToolbar = (Toolbar) bottomSheetLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet_toolbar);
        ImageButton contact_detail_edit = (ImageButton)bottomSheetToolbar.findViewById(R.id.contact_detail_edit);
        ImageButton contact_detail_favorite = (ImageButton)bottomSheetToolbar.findViewById(R.id.contact_detail_favorite);
```